# Azure Table Storage ExecuteBatchAsync not running Async

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, nosql

Good Day,

I am having some trouble with a project that is using Azure Table Storage, in particular I am having issues with getting the ExecuteBatchAsync to actually be Async!  I have reviewed many different articles, examples, and help documents and tried many different scenarios without any luck.  Basically what happens is that every time I call _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation) the code runs in sync instead of async.

```
    public async Task<bool> Save(List<FoundOn> foundOns)
    {

        try
        {

            var batches = new List<Task<IList<TableResult>>>();

            List<List<FoundOn>> groups = foundOns.GroupBy(x => x.SourceURL.ToLower()).Select(s => s.ToList()).ToList();

            foreach (List<FoundOn> sourceRecords in groups)
            {

                var rowId = 0;

                List<PageLinkTableEntity> records = new PageLinkMapper().MapTo(sourceRecords);

                for (var i = 0; i < records.Count; i += TableConstants.TableServiceBatchMaximumOperations)
                {
                    var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

                    List<PageLinkTableEntity> batchItems = records.Skip(i).Take(TableConstants.TableServiceBatchMaximumOperations).ToList();

                    foreach (PageLinkTableEntity item in batchItems)
                    {

                        item.RowKey = $"{item.RowKey}|{rowId}";
                        batchOperation.InsertOrReplace(item);
                        rowId++;

                    }

                    if (batchOperation.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //This line of code takes around 1 second to execute
                        batches.Add(_table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation));
                    }

                }

                if (batches.Count > 20)
                {
                    //This line of code takes 0ms to execute, as there are never any uncompleted tasks
                    await Task.WhenAll(batches);
                    batches.Clear();
                }

            }

            //This line of code takes 0ms to execute, as there are never any uncompleted tasks
            await Task.WhenAll(batches);

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error($"PageLinkRepository: Unable to save found on.  Error: { ex.Message }");
            throw;
        }

    }
```

As you can see in this code block, my method is Async and I am using await Task.WhenAll() to await the tasks in my list.  The problem is, that when I do batches.Add(_table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation)) the code always completes synchronously causing that 1 line to take over 1 second to execute.

I am using a STATIC singleton client as recommended.  Although I have also tried this with a connection created specifically for this 1 method.

```
public static class AzureClient
{

    public static CloudStorageAccount Account { get; set; }
    public static CloudTableClient Client { get; set; }
    static AzureClient()
    {

        Account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"));

        ServicePoint tableServicePoint = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(Account.TableEndpoint);
        tableServicePoint.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
        tableServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        tableServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 100;

        Client = Account.CreateCloudTableClient();

    }

}
```

My data size is relatively small, each record in the batch, as a JSON object is only about 135 bytes, and I have tried both from my workstation to Azure which is on a 300Mbps fiber connection and from a VM on Azure to Azure Storage.  So I don't believe it's a bandwidth/network issue.

I have also tried using:

```
batches.Add(Task.Run(() => _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation)));
```

I am not having problems with any of my other code running in Async.  I am not having any issues with CPU or bandwidth binding, as I am locally on a 12 core / 24 thread dual XEON, and I have tried running on an 8 core Azure VM.

I have also tried decorating my app with the following:

```
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(128, 128);
```

In an effort to try and ensure that I am not running into a connection or thread limit.

Typically I am inserting 4-5 batches, which is taking 5000-9000ms, usually 1000-1500ms per batch.  According to everything I have read, I should be approaching 2000-20000 records per second.  Typically these are going into 1 partition, but I have tried having each batch be a separate partition with no improvement.

I've tried running this from:

Console App
Azure Function
Web API
MVC Controller

All with the same result.  I am guessing I must be doing something wrong, although I can't for the life of me figure out what it might be.

Would greatly appreciate any thoughts/suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation it will initiate an asynchronous operation to execute a batch of operations.

> ExecuteBatchAsync(TableBatchOperation)
>   Initiates an asynchronous operation to execute a batch of operations on a table.

You are initiating it when you add it to your batches operation. You may want to consider just storing a collection of batches and then calling ExecuteBatchAsync on each after you have 20 batches.

Something like this (Check the syntax, I just typed this in notepad ;))

```
public async Task<bool> Save(List<FoundOn> foundOns)
{

    try
    {

        var batches = new List<TableBatchOperation>();

        List<List<FoundOn>> groups = foundOns.GroupBy(x => x.SourceURL.ToLower()).Select(s => s.ToList()).ToList();

        foreach (List<FoundOn> sourceRecords in groups)
        {

            var rowId = 0;

            List<PageLinkTableEntity> records = new PageLinkMapper().MapTo(sourceRecords);

            for (var i = 0; i < records.Count; i += TableConstants.TableServiceBatchMaximumOperations)
            {
                var batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

                List<PageLinkTableEntity> batchItems = records.Skip(i).Take(TableConstants.TableServiceBatchMaximumOperations).ToList();

                foreach (PageLinkTableEntity item in batchItems)
                {

                    item.RowKey = $"{item.RowKey}|{rowId}";
                    batchOperation.InsertOrReplace(item);
                    rowId++;

                }

                if (batchOperation.Count > 0)
                {
                    //This line of code takes around 1 second to execute
                    batches.Add(batchOperation);
                }

            }

            if (batches.Count > 20)
            {
                //This line of code takes 0ms to execute, as there are never any uncompleted tasks
                await Task.WhenAll(batches.Select(c => _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(c)));
                batches.Clear();
            }

        }

        //This line of code takes 0ms to execute, as there are never any uncompleted tasks
        await Task.WhenAll(batches.Select(c => _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(c)));

        return true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error($"PageLinkRepository: Unable to save found on.  Error: { ex.Message }");
        throw;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried this as well, it results in the same thing, they execute one after the other instead of in parallel.  I have also tried using a Parallel.ForEach which has the same result.  Seems that something on the connection is causing them to execute one after the other instead of in parallel.

Comment: What's really weird is that: 

Task.Run(() => _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation));

Should be throwing the task off into a new thread and running it on one of my other fully available cores while my code continues on to create the next batch.  But it seems as though the connection is limiting it to one at a time.